# Merge empty cells with previous value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with around 100,000 records. I have 6+ columns, the first five of which are:

[image: Current Data]

Required Format:

[image]

So far I have :

```
Sub Main()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim sameRows As Boolean
sameRows = True

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To 4
        If StrComp(Cells(i, j), Cells(i + 1, j), vbTextCompare) Then
            sameRows = False
        End If
    Next j

    If sameRows Then
        Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i + 1, 4)).merge
    End If

    sameRows = True
Next i

End Sub
```

I am able to get below by running the macro by changing value in Range from 4 to 1/2/3/4 and running macro four times.

[image]

Please help me get the data in required format. I still need to merge the empty fields with the previous non empty field.

Comment: IMO, you REALLY do not want anything anything but raw data in a 100K record worksheet. You particularly do not want to start mucking around with merged cells. Copy the data from the line above into the blank cells or put it all into a relational database where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pratik, listen carefully to Jeeped. Working with large data in Excel isn't ideal, and working with raw data in merged cells is staring into the abyss - it's a dark, dark place where `Range` referencing and things like `Offset` functions will show you a dimension of despair you never knew existed.

If you have this data in another format, say XML, that you've imported into Excel then use VBA to read the data, query it, etc. in its original format. If it exists in a database, then, again, use VBA to access that database and manipulate the recordsets as you wish. If this is your only source of data, then why not write it into an XML document or into VBA's own data storage options (like `Collection` or arrays).

If you have to use Excel then don't confuse raw data with data display. Yes, the merged cells might be easier to read for the human eye, but I'd just pose the question: is that your primary objective in conducting the merge?

If you must take that leap into the abyss - and you can see that at least two of us would advise against - then at least speed things up by reading from an array and merging rows at a time:

```
Sub OpenDoorsToHades()
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim mergeCells As Range
    Dim mergeAreas As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim blankStart As Long
    Dim blankEnd As Long
    Dim doMerge As Boolean
    Dim c As Integer

    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data") 'rename to your sheet

    'Read values into array of variants
    With dataSheet
        v = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    'Check for blanks
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If IsEmpty(v(i, 1)) Then
            If Not doMerge Then
                blankStart = i - 1
                doMerge = True
            End If
        Else
            If doMerge Then
                blankEnd = i - 1
                For c = 1 To 4
                    With dataSheet
                        Set mergeCells = .Range( _
                                         .Cells(blankStart, c), _
                                         .Cells(blankEnd, c))
                        If mergeAreas Is Nothing Then
                            Set mergeAreas = mergeCells
                        Else
                            Set mergeAreas = .Range(mergeAreas.Address & _
                                                    "," & mergeCells.Address)
                        End If
                    End With

                Next
                mergeAreas.Merge
                Set mergeAreas = Nothing
                doMerge = False
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Format the sheet
    dataSheet.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ambie, it worked perfectly. I had couple huge files from which I had managed to extract this  data and import in excel.

Answer (score 0):

How about just populating the empty cells with the values above, so the values on the far right are associated with the same values that would've been in the merged cell. For example, if 19 is in cell A2, you can recreate the table starting in G2 with =IF(A2<>"",A2,G1), and this way all empty cells will be populated with the value above, pairing the values at the far right with the exact same values.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled the same problem myself this week. Ambie's solution seemed overly complex, so I wrote something pretty simple to merge rows:

```
Sub MergeRows()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim myRow As Long

    'Disable popup alerts that appear when merging rows like this
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    lngStart = 2
    lngEnd = 2

    For myRow = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
        If Range("A" & (myRow + 1)).value = "" Then
            'include row below in next merge
            lngEnd = myRow + 1
        Else
            'merge if 2+ rows are included
            If lngEnd - lngStart > 0 Then
                Range("A" & lngStart & ":A" & lngEnd).Merge
                Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd).Merge
                Range("C" & lngStart & ":C" & lngEnd).Merge
                Range("D" & lngStart & ":D" & lngEnd).Merge
            End If

            'reset included rows
            lngStart = myRow + 1
            lngEnd = myRow + 1
        End If
    Next myRow

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```